# How to use Xcode 6 to install two different iOS apps into same time

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I am a fresh ios developer.I want to make a package for two ios application.I have done it with android development.When i install project one ,then automatically installed project two into my android device.Just i add project two with project one.It is installed two application on android device with two different icons.But i don't understand how i will install two ios app/projects into ios device through one application.It is so important for me.Please give me some way to complete my projects.

Comment: You cannot do this with iOS and Xcode - only one app target can be selected installed at a time - this is the same as with the AppStore - the user installs a single app at a time.

Comment: Yup, you can do it android device but not with iPhone.